# How to checkout to another remote without merging

Tags: git, checkout

I don't know if it is duplicate, but I didn't find someone describing exactly what I want to do.

I have a local repository with an origin remote URL. I needed to make some more commits to push to another URL (which I'll call test_remote). I don't want those new commits from test_remote in the origin remote, and I want to keep working from the last commit of origin remote (Origin/master). How do I checkout my local repository to the origin without messing with both remote repositories?
I know I could simply clone from origin and ignore the old local repository, but I'm curious if it's possible to just checkout to different remotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you basically want 2 things:

1. to push some of your commits only to one of the remotes
2. to keep those changes only in the test_remote, while origin doesn't know about them at all.

Well, looks like it's a combination of actions. First, you have to use branches to keep your changes separate. And likely the single main branch to avoid conflicts when you need to merge. Second, you push each branch to the remote of your choice. Like so:

I want to fix a function from main and push it to origin. To do that, I do:

- `git switch main`
- `git pull`
- `git switch -c fix-func-origin`
- (fix the code)
- `git commit -am "my comment"`
- `git push -u origin fix-func-origin`

Fine, now I want to experiment with this function so that no one who has access to origin can see it. For that I do:

- `git switch main`
- `git pull`
- `git switch -c experiment-func-test`
- (fix the code)
- `git commit -am "my comment"`
- `git push -u test_remote experiment-func-test`

I wonder if it makes sense.

---

**UPD**: some updates for the situation when commits have already been made to main, sent to test_remote and are not welcome in origin.

So, suppose you committed the changes into the main branch and now you have to somehow deal with the origin. Well there seems to be a bunch of ways to fix it. For instance, you could reset the local HEAD in master one commit back `git reset --hard HEAD^`. This way it will look like somebody added some commits to test_remote/main, but you haven't pulled them yet. But I think it's generally a bad idea to mess with main. It should be stable and only communicate with the official remote, to avoid contradictory history. So, in this case I think I would:

- create a new branch from the modified main (that will keep all the changes).
- push it to test_remote for backup
- hard reset main to the previous commit, like nothing happened
- possibly never deal with the test_remote/main (as it is not the official version anyway) and only use this remote to back up my experimental branches. Which will either perform well and later get merged to origin/main or fail and get deleted.

Comment: Thansks! It makes sense, and I'll do that next time. But in my case now, I've already commited the new changes, but instead of pushing to origin I've added test_remote and then push (git remote add test_remote URL && git push -u test_remote master). So my local repo has the new commit and I'd like to checkout to the HEAD of origin remote (one commit behind) without being with detached HEAD.

Comment: Tried to reply here, but my message seems to long, so I'll edit my answer to add some considerations about this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use 'git stash' on your local repository.

You can read the documentation here :
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash